# Express doesn't return 304 for static json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm using `express.static` to serve a very large, static json file.  While `express.static` will return 304 when other static resources are unchanged, it always returns 200 for static json.

Because of the size of the file and the nature of my application, I want to avoid clients downloading the file unless it has changed.

How can I convince express to return 304 for my json?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the [status](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) code in the return:

```
res.status(304).json({ data: 'data' }); // or 200
```

Comment: 304 is "Not Modified". It's used to let the browser know they can use cached content rather than re-downloading it. Unless Express does some intelligent handling based on forced response codes, this answer completely misses the point.